# Send JSON Data for Debugging

Tags: javascript, json, debugging, rest

I would like to debug client side applications by manually creating a JSON data stream. I was hoping that Google Chrome's debug console would be able to do this.

For example, consider the following case. I want to test how a list population code segment would work. Let's say I have item objects of the format: {"name" : "test", "price" : "10"}. Instead of actually coding this up on the server, I would like to generate this data locally and send it for testing purposes.

The Javascript would look something like this:

```
//JQuery AJAX call to request data
$.getJSON('some_url', function(data) {

     //Go through each received JSON element (assuming array input) and
     //log its key value pair to the debug console (using Google Chrome as example)
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
          console.log("Key is: " + key + " value is: " + value);
     }

});//End getJSON
```

I would want to make a list of data (perhaps in a text file?) like so:

```
{"name" : "paper", "price" : "5"}
{"name" : "bear repellent", "price" : "10"}
```

I would then like to pass this data into the function to see if it works and see the output (accomplished here by the console.log() call). I understand that this is somewhat like unit testing, and my research indicates that this might be the job for a REST client. However, I am unsure how to accomplish this. Input is appreciated.

Comment: Can't Google Chrome do this, as you already said?

Comment: Have you ever heard of [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)?

Comment: @Seza, good question. I think it should be able to, but its documentation does not show how to do it.

Comment: @epascarello, just looked into it. It has some promising features to it. I will investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track with your idea of creating a text file. In fact, that is all you need to do: put your JSON data in a text file and use the URL to that text file in your `$.getJSON()` call. For pure JSON, this file will need to be loaded from the same domain as your HTML page (and in fact you would normally use a relative URL in the `$.getJSON()` call.

So the first thing is to make valid JSON for your data, which it isn't yet:

```json
[
    { "name": "paper", "price": "5" },
    { "name": "bear repellent", "price": "10" }
]
```

The whitespace isn't significant; you can format whitespace any way you like.

You can test that you have valid JSON by pasting it into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

So if you put that data in a text file called `'testdata.json'` in the same directory as your HTML page, then you can simply use `'testdata.json'` as your URL in the `$.getJSON()` call.

Also, this bit of code doesn't quite make sense as written, or at least the names are misleading.

```js
// Go through each received JSON element (assuming array input) and
// log its key value pair to the debug console (using Google Chrome
// as example)
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log("Key is: " + key + " value is: " + value);
});
```

(I fixed a couple of simple typos in this copy of the code.)

That `$.each()` will iterate over the entire array, so your `console.log()` calls are going to print:

```
Key is: 0 value is: [object Object]
Key is: 1 value is: [object Object]
```

Now one thing you can do to get a more useful printout is to use individual arguments separated by commas instead of string concatenation in the `console.log()` call:

```js
console.log( "Key is: ", key, " value is: ", value );
```

Because `value` is an object, `console.log()` is smart enough to log it as such—if you give it a chance to do so by passing it as a separate argument like this. When it's concatenated into a string with the `+` operator you lose that.

But more importantly, the code you want is probably something like this:

```js
// Loop through the elements of the JSON array, and for each one
// log its `name` and `price` properties.
$.each( data, function( i, item ) {
    console.log(
        'Item number:', i,
        '| name:', item.name,
        '| price:', item.price
    );
});
```

which should print:

```
Item number: 0 | name: paper | price: 5
Item number: 1 | name: bear repellent | price: 10
```

(The vertical bars aren't anything significant; they're just to format the output a little bit.)

I would also suggest not using an array as the top level of your JSON data, but make it an object instead and put your array inside it:

```json
{
    "items": [
        { "name": "paper", "price": "5" },
        { "name": "bear repellent", "price": "10" }
    ]
}
```

The only change you'll need to make in the code is to use `$.each(data.items,...)` instead of `$.each(data,...)`.

The main reason to do this is that it is more future-proof: what if you later want to add information to your JSON response that doesn't pertain to a single item in your array but applies to the data/array as a whole? Using an object at the top level makes this simple:

```json
{
    "someglobalthing": "Hello world!",
    "items": [
        { "name": "paper", "price": "5" },
        { "name": "bear repellent", "price": "10" }
    ]
}
```

and your code that refers to `json.items` doesn't have to change at all.

There's also a possible security issue with a top-level JSON array. I think it's fixed in modern browsers, but the top-level object is more versatile anyway.

Comment: Michael, excellent write up. Thanks for the tip about the future-proofing. I may not have made this clear, but I was more concerned about how I would simulate that AJAX traffic. Often, I need to simulate when a GET or POST sends JSON data, and determine how to prevent failures when the data takes too long to arrive or other corner cases. @epascarello suggested Fiddler, and that may be the way to "inject" this traffic for debugging purposes. Do you have any input on this?

Comment: @DiodeDan - Oh yes, I definitely second that recommendation. Fiddler is an outstanding tool. I've used it for many years, although somewhat less lately as the built-in browser dev tools have gotten more powerful. But when you need more than they provide, Fiddler is top-notch. Be sure to go to the [Add-ons page](http://fiddler2.com/add-ons) and get the JavaScript formatter, syntax-highlighting package (which includes the FiddlerScript editor), per-response latency extension, and any others that catch your attention.

Comment: @DiodeDan - Also recommended is the [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/). This may be built into Fiddler now, but this download also gives you a nice standalone JSON viewer. I also see there are several versions of Fiddler now - if you're on Windows 8 the [Fiddler4 version is recommended by Eric Law](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/httpfiddler/KosjL9-uHZo), the Fiddler author.

Comment: @DiodeDan - One more recommendation - the [Debugging with Fiddler](http://fiddlerbook.com/book/) book is excellent - definitely worth the ten bucks for the PDF download.

Comment: @DiodeDan - Another Fiddler tip or two (I'll add these to the answer later and clean up the comments) - the Filters and AutoResponder tabs are where you'll want to look for some of the tests you want to do, and the FiddlerScript where you can just about anything by scripting it. Also consider combining static JSON test files with Fiddler - static files for the easy tests and Fiddler for stress testing and experimentation. You can also use Fiddler to redirect your Ajax requests from the normal server to your test data files.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a js file in the following format

```
var tempData = [
   {name : "paper", price : 5},
   {name : "bear repellent", price : 10},
];
```

Add this file to your page using `<script>` tag

Then use the `tempData` object as data in your function call